# How to outsource password and account management to a third party?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, openid

I read that storing passwords yourself, handling lost passwords and accounts etc, is a complicated process, and involves a lot of work if you don't want to take security risks.

I am building a website for which security is very important. I thought it would be good to start with not trying to handle that myself, but outsource it to an external service.

What I am looking for is something a bit like "Log in with Facebook", or "Log in with Google", except that :

- I can't use those websites nor Twitter because in themselves I will propose later on to users to link their accounts on those services, so it can be confusing if I also use them for password and account management. (For example, someone coming to the site to link to Twitter wouldn't understand if I ask them to login with Facebook)
- I'd like to enable users to easily have an account just for my website. If using their Google account, it is used on other websites as well (at least for Gmail for example). What I would like is for users to be able to create an account just for my website.

Any idea of a service provider for this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

- [parse.com](https://parse.com/)
- [stormpath.com](https://stormpath.com/)
- [auth0.com](https://auth0.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I tried to look at these three options, and it seems that for me the best would be auth0. Just to make sure I understood how they work :

Comment: - Parse provides a service through an API, which would enable me to create users with passwords, and send email verification emails, by just a call to their API, however the user interface for that is up to me, and password forgotten workflow is not provided either.
- Stormpath does exactly all I need through an API, but I still need to build all the user interface part
- Auth0 does everything, and includes an easily customizable user interface. 
Is that correct ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know details about the services.

Comment: As for Stormpath, I found it when tranlating a tutorial of Apache Shiro (http://shiro.apache.org/webapp-tutorial.html). Parse.com is famous because Facebook has acquired it. Auth0 is listed in the libraries section of OpenID Connect. The keywords are OAuth, authentication, authorization and BaaS (Backend As A Service).

Comment: parse.com is [winding down as of January 2017](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/). I noticed also that [UserApp](http://help.userapp.io/customer/portal/questions/10726272-is-userapp-still-being-developed-and-supported-) is long dead. The two that so far are standing the test of "google search" are Stormpath & Auth0. Just pray they stay up and healthy. Devise mentioned by @james below feels new and not sure if they will stick around.

Comment: @lukik kind of sad that Stormpath shut down just a few months after your comment. :D

Comment: @NickCox wonder who's left now in this space. I kinda jinxed it in my original comment though :-(

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to give you a heads up that Stormpath now includes user interfaces in two ways:

1. Our [ID Site feature](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/using-id-site/) which is basically hosted login screens you can use with any app (or even centralize login across multiple apps).
2. Views and default screens built into framework-specific sample apps:

   - [Stormpath-Express](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express)
   - [Stormpath-Passport-Express](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-passport-express-sample)
   - [Stormpath-Flask](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-flask-sample)

We're working to get screens into all of our sample apps, so let us know if you're looking for something in particular. We can probably get you some code to get started. support@stormpath.com

Answer (score 2):

If it's helpful for anyone else, I compared (5/18/2015):

- Auth0
- AuthRocket
- UserApp
- DailyCred

**Conclusion for me was Auth0**, because while all the features are very similar, it felt the most legitimate, as in it's not a start-up that might disappear in a few months. Now, the reason that was super important for me was because login is a foundational requirement, so I need to believe as a customer that the Authentication as a Service will be up for as long as I will be.

Here's the full comparison story:
https://medium.com/@bsemaj/authentication-as-a-service-comparison-5-quick-lessons-for-b2b-businesses-e7587275824c

Comment: Ironically, after all 3 days I ditched Auth0 in favor of Devise. I just found the documentation too lacking after all and frustrating to work with. There were so many commands that I thought would be really obviously well documented, e.g., how to sign up, sign in, sign out, change email, change password, but often times I had to go to the source code... My gold standard for docs is Stripe